# Distance: point to plane

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose that $E = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ is a point and $P$ is a plane described by the equation $A(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0) +C(z-z_0)= Ax+By+Cz+D = 0$.

[image]

Since the distance from $E$ to $P$ is the length of the projection of $\vec{RE}$ onto the normal vector $\vec{n}$ and **by the formula of projection**, I think we have

$$\text{distance} = \frac{\vec{RE}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||^2} = \frac{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||^2}.$$

Why does the distance from $E$ to $P$ equal 
$$\frac{|Ax_1 + By_1 + Cz_1 + D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}} = \frac{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||}$$

instead of

$$\frac{|Ax_1 + By_1 + Cz_1 + D|}{A^2+B^2+C^2}= \frac{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||^2}?$$

Comment: $a\cdot b=\|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta $, right?

Comment: @ThomasShelby How does this explain that we should have  $\frac{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||}$? By the formula of projection, shouldn't we have  $\frac{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||^2}$?

Comment: Sorry, I may be wrong. But I think you are confusing scalar projection with vector projection. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the formula $$\text{distance} = \frac{\vec{RE}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||^2}$$

The correct formula is $$\text{distance} = \frac{\vec{RE}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||}.$$

which gives you the correct result $$\frac{|Ax_1 + By_1 + Cz_1 + D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$

Note that $$\text{distance} =||\vec{RE}||\cos(\theta)= \frac{\vec{RE}\cdot \vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||}$$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{RE}$ and $\vec{n}$, then the distance is $||\vec{RE}|||\cos\theta|$, which is $\displaystyle \left|\frac{||\vec{RE}||||\vec{n}||\cos\theta}{||\vec{n}||}\right|=\frac{|\vec{RE}\cdot\vec{n}|}{||\vec{n}||}$